# Disabling pasting into window.prompt()

Tags: javascript

I have a web application used internally by users to enter data. The product owners decided they want to remove the users ability to paste data into a prompt that is used to make them dual key the data entered. I know of no way (and found nothing through my searching) to implement this behavior in a prompt. The application does not use jQuery, just straight JS.

I recommended just disabling copy functionality for the entire page, but they specifically want to disable pasting into the prompt. Is this feasible? If so, how can I go about implementing it?

Comment: Well, you can think outside the box and use a modal instead (you can build a simple one using mostly CSS). That way, you can use `<input>` where you *can* prevent input.

Comment: Don’t forget Linux’ middle-click pasting.

Comment: use your own input dialog

Comment: Oh, and don’t forget drag-and-drop inputs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible I'm afraid. `prompt()` is an API built by the browser, and much like `alert()`, once the popup window is opened it blocks processing on the page itself, so you have no way of knowing what keys/clicks the user has carried out on the popup, other than the text they enter into it which you receive in the response.

Comment: But the point is the JavaScript on her/his page will not be processing while those key and click events are happening, so the listeners will never fire. It's designed this way - the popup is essentially the same technology used to enter .htaccess passwords (http://i.imgur.com/JGWX00n.png). There are obvious reasons why you shouldn't be able to listen to key/click events on those popups.

Comment: I see, so que answer is: don't use a prompt